# Obtener los 5 últimos valores de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array:

```
aNumeros=[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12];
```

quiero crear otro array a partir de ese, que contenga los 5 ultimos numeros:

```
aNuevo= [7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
```

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando la función splice, pasando como parámetro la posición desde donde quieres recortar.

```js
let aNumeros=[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12];
let aNuevo = aNumeros.slice(aNumeros.length-5)
console.log(aNuevo)
```

En este caso como posición de inicio le pasamos la longitud del array(aNumeros) y le restamos 5, por lo cual siempre buscaremos los 5 últimos.

> Si no hay posición de final, nos dejara  un nuevo array con los elementos desde la posición inicio y hasta el final.

Hecha un vistazo a la documentación, para ver como funciona mas detalladamente 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

Con el fin de dar respuesta a tu inquietud te comparto el siguiente segmento de código, espero te sea de utilidad, saludos:

```
<script>
  // uso del evento ready de jQuery para generar el example requerido
  $(function() {

    // arreglo inicial (en orden aleatorio)
    var aNumeros=[1, 6, 5, 8, 7, 9, 12, 10];

    // impresion de arreglo inicial
    console.log("aNumeros: " + aNumeros.toString());

    // arreglo ordenado usando function nativas de js
    var arrOrdenado = aNumeros.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

    // impresion de arr ordenado
    console.log("arrOrdenado: " + arrOrdenado.toString());                
    // uso de la function slice luego del ordenamiento para cortar 

    var aNuevo = arrOrdenado.slice(arrOrdenado.length-5)                
    // impresion del arr que requieres...
    console.log("aNuevo: " + aNuevo.toString());                
    // fin de function ready de jQuery          
  });
// fin de segmento de javascript
</script>
```

Comment: primer comentario, solo poner código se considera de baja calidad, explica que hace lo que pones, segundo deberías aclarar que tu ejemplo esta escrito al usar `$` con jquery

Comment: oki ya estoy redactando mejor mi rpta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion similar a la de [Eugeni Bejan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/212346/28035), coloca -valor y te devolvera lo indicado, no es necesario obtener la longitud

```js
let aNumeros=[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12];
console.log(aNumeros.slice(-5))
```